# Arduino + C# + RFID?

Tags: c#, winforms, arduino

Consigo pegar o `id` da `tag` com esse trecho de código e jogar em uma `Textbox`, mas, teria como pegar a informação de qual leitor `RFID` ela foi lida?

```
serialPort1.Open();
string entrada = serialPort1.ReadLine();
serialPort1.Close();
txt_tag.Text = entrada;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for um arduino com dois leitores, no código do arduino vc envia um código que identifique de qual leitor veio concatenado com a id lida, utilize um char para separar os dois valores ';' por exemplo, quando receber o valor, utilize o comendo valor.split(';'); para obter os valores separados.